# Can programatically PUT to Amazon S3 bucket but not DELETE

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, http-delete

My users can programically upload images to the AWS S3 bucket fine. But using the same  php S3 class include (which contains the *put case* as well as this *delete case* below) -- they can't delete the file:

```
        case 'DELETE':
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'DELETE');
        break;
```

So I'm wondering if any sharp eye out there can see what I'm missing in my scripts. I'm not getting any error messages. -thanks

```
   //THIS WORKS

              //include the S3 class
            if (!class_exists('S3'))require_once('S3.php');

    //GET keys   
   include_once "scripts/S3k.php";  


//instantiate the class
$s3 = new S3(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);       

   //assigns file location var to get
    $fileTempName = $DestinationFile;  
  //Assigns S3 path/file name
    $fileName = $path.$user_id."/".$fileName;

//Move the file over to S3
    if ($s3->putObjectFile($fileTempName, $mybucket, $fileName, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ)) { 
    echo " file uploaded";
}               


//THIS  doesn't  WORKS

//include the S3 class
if (!class_exists('S3'))require('S3.php');

//get KEYS
include "scripts/S3k.php";  

 //instantiate the class
    $s3 = new S3(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);       

//Assigns S3 path/file name
    $fileName = $path.$user_id."/".$image_link;

//Deletes the file in S3
     if ($s3->deleteObject($mybucket, $fileName)) {
    echo "Deleted file.";
}               

//And this GET script doesn't work either.
  $image_link = "1/Bowery_3_58x46app.jpg";
  $pathS3 = "http://d21v2uajc20x0x.cloudfront.net/myGallerist/artWorkImages/";

//include the S3 class
if (!class_exists('S3'))require_once('S3.php');

include_once "scripts/S3k.php"; 

//instantiate the class
$s3 = new S3(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);       

// Get the file from S3

    if ($s3->getObject($mybucket, $pathS3.$image_link, "tempImage/".$image_link )) {        

         } else {

            // Couldn't move the file over. 
             $msgToUser = 'No file was uploaded.';
    }
```

Comment: Please post the error message you get in the S3 response to your DELETE request.

Answer (score 1):

I can be wrong but seems like it could be an issue with the bucket name , in delete you are using a variable as the bucketname where as in put object you have hard coded the bucket name , can you please verify that the variable contains the correct bucket name?

Edit:
Also you should try to echo the $fileName in both cases and make sure they are exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks for replying. No, the bucket names were both "mobiarts". Thought it would be best to replace with vars just for this question and I only replaced one of them by mistake.

Comment: and what about the $fileName . are those correct? Also please post the S3 error that you get on delete.

Comment: Yes, the $fileName checks out. Same setup as PUT script. No error message. I just added a getObject script that's broken also w/o error message. -thanks, Allen

Comment: Got a tip to switch to S3 bucket uri's (and confirmed working) instead of cloudfront uri's. But no luck yet